# SystemVerilog: convert two 1D array into 2D array

Tags: system-verilog

```
logic [7:0] a;
logic [7:0] b;
logic [1:0][7:0] c;
assign c = {{a},{b}};
```

If I had a and b, how could I convert it into type of c?
I guess one obvious way is to use:

```
assign c[0] = a;
assign c[1] = b;
```

But imagine c was not a logic variable, but a input port of a module.

```
mymodule inst_mymodule (
    .c_i({{a},{b}}) // c is logic [1:0][7:0]
    .o(out)
);
```

what would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using packed arrays, it does not matter what the type of `c` is. It just needs to be 16 bits. Also you don’t need the extra {}’s around `a` and `b`. You can write `{a,b}`

Comment: Isn't the type of {a,b} same as logic [15:0]?

Comment: Yes it is the same as `logic [15:0]` which is assignment compatible with `logic [1:0][7:0]`